# Pass class object as parameter to POST method in php laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to PHP Laravel development. Can anyone suggest me how to send class object (model object) as parameter in POST method using Laravel 5.3

If anyone having example, please share.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: do you have any existing code

Comment: I am trying to call searchMOP method of OperationController. For my application, all routes are defined in web.php file under routes folder. 
From web.config

     Route::post('/API/operations/searchMOP', function(App\Http\Database\SearchMOPModel $searchMOPModel)
     {
     return redirect()->route('/API/operations/searchMOP', [$searchMOPModel]); 
     });

From OperationController.php 

     public function searchMOP(SearchMOPModel $searchMOPModel)   
     {
     // My Code Here
     return "From searchMOP()"; 
     }

Pls suggest me proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution on my own try & error methods that want to share with you. 
In web.config just declare route without any parameter as follows :

```
Route::post('/API/operations/searchMOP', ['uses' => 'OperationController@searchMOP']);
```

In OperationController, define method as follows :

```
public function searchMOP(Request $searchMOP)    
{       
    return "MOPno:" . $searchMOP->mopno . ", MOP:" . $searchMOP->mop;
    // My Processing..... 
}
```

Don't know, how Laravel will take model automatically in Controller. If anyone has idea OR other solution for same problem, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a model object is a terrible idea, just pass an ID and get it in the next request. Using the form data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $modelData = Model::find($request->id);
```

Using URI:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $modelData = Model::find($id);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey for quick reply But I want to pass model object. I have many search criteria on page so passing that values one by one will not advisable. 

I refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses (check Populating Parameters Via Eloquent Models) and https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing (check Explicit Binding) but still have something missing.

Comment: @UmeshAp when you're using explicit binding, Laravel will still execute DB query to get model data. Also, you can't pass a whole object, you can serialize data and pass it and then unserialize it, but still this will no be an original object.

Comment: Can you please give sample example for my case. I don't understand anything. Actually I have ready application in Java & trying to convert in php Laravel framework. All over application, created models for search & insert into DB. I ma avoiding major chnages so need of passing model object to controller. Pls Pls provide sample example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: :@Alexey Mezenin
Please provide sample example to route POST request with class object as parameter. I am struggling whole day for the same.